# parsing parameters in shell script

Tags: shell

I have a myscript.sh which starts like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

usage(){
  echo "Show Usage ... Blah blah"
  exit 1
}

if [ $# = 0 ]; then
  usage;
fi

while true; do
  case "$1" in
    -l | --build-lib ) BUILD_LIB=true; 
    --other-option ) OTHER_OPTION=$2; shift; shift;;
    -h | --help ) usage; shift;;
    * ) break ;;
  esac
done

# I do my thing here ....
echo "Do my thing"
```

I am not sure if this is the best way to parse the parameters but so far I have a problem. I am not correctly breaking/failing when the user passes wrong or unknown parameters. How can I address this correctly?

for example I want to avoid calls like:

```
$ ./myscript.sh unknownParameter
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to exit when an incorrect option is given, not just break out of the loop. Easiest way is to call your `usage` function.

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
  case "$1" in
    -l | --build-lib ) BUILD_LIB=tru ;;
    --xcode-dev-path ) XCODE_DEV_PATH=${2%/}; shift ;;
    -h | --help ) usage;;
    * ) usage ;;
  esac
  shift
done
```

Comment: I see that you are using one `shitf;;` less than me after checking each parameter. How come this is posible? I thought shift was needed to go to the next parameter.  - I am kind of lost in shell.

Comment: I added `shift` at the bottom of the loop. You always need to shift after each arg, so it's redundant to put that one in each case.

Comment: This didn't work as expected. Indeed, I can now avoid calls like `$ ./myscript.sh unknownParameter` but now I cannot even pass correct parameters like `$ ./myscript.sh -l` since `*)` is apparently always reached :(

Comment: I fixed the missing `;;` after the `-h` case, and changed the `while` condition so the loop will exit. Does that help? Why aren't you using `getopt`, anyway?

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much. I guess I should learn how to use `getopt` for proper argument handling.